# Titanium / Android module: extending map annotation function

Tags: android, google-maps, titanium

Does anyone have any idea how I would go about extending the functionality of Titanium's map methods? Specifically overriding Ti.Map.createAnnotation? I'm trying to create custom pins, and I can do it by generating the images in java, but I'd rather be able to override Titanium's native createAnnotation code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is just to update the source code yourself. Fork the source of https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile.  The classes you want to change are in https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/tree/master/android/modules/map/src/java/ti/modules/titanium/map.  See the Appcelerator wiki for example on how to build from source.

I'd recommend you create your own 'createSpecialAnnotation' method and call that from your JavaScript code.  That way if the source changes, you can just re-add your own method.

Comment: Hey thanks Jeff. I've been trying to do it by creating a module, since it's for a client, which is proving to be quite difficult. Do you know if it's possible to pass the js Ti.Mapview object to the Java code? Or do I need to reference the mapview from the Context that is passed to the Java module? (which I've been trying to do but have had no luck).

Comment: I also made a module, but I needed to copy all the source from version 1.7.5 titanium/map as a starting point and put in my own package. The only object I could 'reuse' was TiMapActivity from Titanium.  The only gotcha I found was I needed to have a line Ti.Map.createView in my code to make sure the Map Module was included.  Drop me an email at jeffb #AT# gameshape dot com and I'll be happy to share the code.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, sent you an email.

Comment: Thanks for the info @JeffBonnes, is it possible to share with the community the module?